# fresh installation only shows a "dash"

Tags: boot, macbook

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my old macbook. Installation was succsessfull. There was an error befor booting: efi wasn't loadable. I fixed that. But Ubuntu doesn't start.
I only see a dos cursor (don't know the name) "  -  " <-- 
And it is blinking. Thats all. I tried changing my Touchpad configuration... because that worked before. (Don't ask why. The world is mysterious.)
Does anyone have an idea? :)

Greetings Meee

PS: 12.04 works just fine

Comment: To me it looks like you will have to reinstall Ubuntu, as that blinking cursor generally indicates that there is no bootable operating system.

Comment: Well, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it is updating now. But thats no real solution. The Os was installed. Or at least the files were there. 

I already had 14.04 but wanted to have a clean installation. But I doubt, that I will try that again in the next months.

Comment: Ok. Now I cant upgrade 12.04.2 either. 
14.04 Was installed without warnings and gave me that cursor. 
after an upgrade of 12.04.2 to 12.10 I've got a black screen.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?! I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: I solved that by not deleting the old files when the installationwizard wants to delete them. Maybe there are some files that are imortant for booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just startet to rebuild my laptop OSs again. 
I now have a solution to the Problem I ddiscribed. The "dash" implicates that the efiboot-partition is missing/not bootable. Ubuntu doesn't create it on its own. The Installaion was fine. To fix the boot error the Partitiontable had to be selfmade. Important is a efiboot-partition in the beginning of the boottable. Now Ubuntu works fine and starts without a Problem.

For everybody that isnt sure if his Macbook / MacbookPro has all the needed firmwareupdates:
Go to: 
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518
You have to use Mac to install the firmware. (I installed it on an extra harddisk)

The message Efi/Boot/fallback.efi 14 isn't important.

Have a nice day!
and thanks for your Help!